# How to create fact and dimension tables for single hive table along with incremental data

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am new to create a Data warehouse(star schema) in hive.My requirement is,i am able to get one hive table along with incremental data using sqoop job.For this hive table I have to create Fact and Dimension tables along with updated data continuously.
Is it possible in Hive,if yes how to create.If no what is the another approach.
If anybody have any idea please share with me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use certain steps to automate your requirement

1. create a shell script which will contain your hive query for
   creating Fact & Dimension table

eg. `your_shell_script.sh` will contain code

```
#!/bin/sh

hive -e "use hivedb; CREATE TABLE FACTS as select your columns from Source_table;"

hive -e "use hivedb; CREATE TABLE DIMENSIONS as Select your coloumns from Source_table;"
```

**Note:** you can use any create table method you want to use, depends upon how you want to create your tables, you can add partitions also.

2. Start Crontab deamon of your Linux OS.
3. Make a [Crontab entry](https://crontab.guru/) in your Linux which will execute your shell script at certain time after your main source table sqoop uploading is complete.

eg. `crontab -e`

```
0 11 * * * /path/to/your/script/your_shell_script.sh
```

note this crontab entry will run your shell script at 11 AM in morning ( after your sqoop loading)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for reply.I have a small doubt.how it will get incremental data into fact and dimension tables everytime?

Comment: thats what i have written in note.. you can either insert overwrite your table every time you load new data. OR you can use partitions so that each time you store incremented data in new partitions based on date or something else

Comment: Ok.Thanks for your reply.yes this is helpful for me.